# why i get null on getView?

Tags: android

why i get null on the following code when i use getView?

```
public void menuItemSelected(int itemId) {


        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
        ft.replace(R.layout.fragment_main, mShoppingCartFragment, "ShoppingCartFragment"); 
        ft.commit();
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        View aaa = mShoppingCartFragment.getView(); <-- null here
        TextView fk = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1); <-- null here
        fk.setText("clicked by " + itemId);

    }
```

Comment: Please post your logcat to point where's that `null`

Comment: What `getView` of `mShoppingCartFragment` return? And i think you want to change `findViewById(R.id.textView1);` to `aaa.findViewById(R.id.textView1);`

Comment: aaa is null, getView returns null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [FragmentTransaction.commit()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commit%28%29) is an asynchronous call, hence it doesn't return immediatly. So, your Fragment could be null, if you call `View aaa = mShoppingCartFragment.getView();` right after it.

Furthermore [Fragment.getView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getView%28%29) will be null, if the callback `onCreateView(...)` hasn't returned or you return null for it, which means there is no View associated with this Fragment.

Both is possible in your code snippet.

If `TextView fk = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);` returns null make sure, the id textView1 is part of the layout of the Activity. If it's a View for the Fragment get the reference there.

Comment: i understand , then how can i do this in different way that when i create the fragment i change something inside it according to some input that just happened ?

Answer (score 1):

As Steve mentioned [FragmentTransaction.commit()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commit%28%29)

is an asynchronous call, but you can always call to:

```
ft.executePendingTransactions();
```

And you will block on this method until all the pending transactions will complete